# Proof of completion of a measure is complete

Tags: measure-theory

i'm studying using the book "Probability and measrue Theory" - Robert B. Ash. To show that completion of a measure is complete he wrote this demonstration,

"Note that the completion is in fact complete, for if $M\subset A \cup N \in \mathscr{F}_u$ where $A \in \mathscr{F}, \mu(A)=0, N \subset B, \mu(B)=0$ then $M\subset A\cup B \in \mathscr{F}, \mu(A \cup B) =0;$ hence $M \in \mathscr{F}_\mu$".

I didn't understood why $\mu(B)=0$, and why it proves that if $\mu(A)=0, A \in \mathscr{F}_\mu$ any subset $M$ of $A$ is in $\mathscr{F}_\mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify that the completion is complete, you have to prove that any subset of a null set of the completion is having measure zero.

And any element of the completion can be written as the union of an element of the initial $\sigma$-algebra and an element included in a measure zero set. This is why $\mu(B)$ is supposed to be equal to $0$.

Then $\mu(A \cup B) \le \mu(A)+\mu(B)$.